# How to convert Java `Consumer` to Groovy `Closure`?

Tags: java, groovy

I have some Java code that needs to call a Groovy API that takes a `Closure` as a parameter. How do I go about converting a Java `Consumer` to a Groovy `Closure`? The code looks something like:

```
final Consumer<Example> consumer = (Example e) -> {
  e.doSomething();
};
someGroovyApi(convertConsumerToClosure(consumer));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MethodClosure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/MethodClosure.html) to convert a `Consumer` (or any other functional interface) to a `Closure`.

```
Closure closure = new MethodClosure(consumer, "accept");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to convert the `Consumer` into a `Closure`, just create the equivalent `Closure`, something like:

```
new Closure<Example>(outerObject) {
  public Example call(final Object o) {
    final Example e = (Example) o;

    e.doSomething();

    return e;
  }
}
```